# Iterative creation of csv files by series in Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a dataframe, `df` which looks like this:

```
Site    Roadname    Count   id  Count_norm
9   A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond    1474    9SOUTHBOUND 1428
9   A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond    1375    9SOUTHBOUND 1329
9   A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond    1052    9SOUTHBOUND 1006
9   A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond    986     9SOUTHBOUND 940
9   A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond    1071    9SOUTHBOUND 1025
9   A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond    1206    9SOUTHBOUND 1160
9   A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond    1474    9NORTHBOUND 1428
9   A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond    1375    9NORTHBOUND 1329
9   A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond    1052    9NORTHBOUND 1006
9   A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond    986     9NORTHBOUND 940
9   A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond    1071    9NORTHBOUND 1025
9   A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond    1206    9NORTHBOUND 1160
```

I can create separate csv's by series by:

```
11N_series = results[results.id == "11NORTHBOUND"]
11N_series.to_csv('./11NORTHBOUND.csv')
```

However, this requires me to define the name of each series (`id`)

How can I iterate through the `df` dataframe and export a csv per `id`?

I can see the count per id and the name by:

```
[in] id_count = results.groupby(["id"]).size()
print(id_count)

[out]
id
11NORTHBOUND    467
11SOUTHBOUND    467
15NORTHBOUND    467
```

Comment: After grouping you can call groups to return a dict of the groups and then `get_group` for a specific group will return a df keyed on that group see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups and http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

st = """
Site|Roadname|Count|id|Count_norm
9|A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond|1474|9SOUTHBOUND|1428
9|A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond|1375|9SOUTHBOUND|1329
9|A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond|1052|9SOUTHBOUND|1006
9|A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond|986|9SOUTHBOUND|940
9|A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond|1071|9SOUTHBOUND|1025
9|A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond|1206|9SOUTHBOUND|1160
9|A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond|1474|9NORTHBOUND|1428
9|A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond|1375|9NORTHBOUND|1329
9|A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond|1052|9NORTHBOUND|1006
9|A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond|986|9NORTHBOUND|940
9|A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond|1071|9NORTHBOUND|1025
9|A316 Twickenham Rd, Richmond|1206|9NORTHBOUND|1160
""" 

data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(st), delimiter="|", error_bad_lines=False) 

#get a list of unique ids 
ids = pd.unique(data["id"].values.ravel())

grouped_data = data.groupby("id")
for id in ids:
    #get the dataframe for the current id 
    df = grouped_data.get_group(id)
    #export current id's dataframe to a csv file with its name 
    df.to_csv(str(id)+".csv", sep="|", index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks! I should point out that for csv the delimiter should be "," not "|"